# What is the recommended way to completely customize UI widgets in Flutter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

I have been reading some of the Flutter documentation, wondering what the best way is to make completely custom designs. I have come across the following image in flutter's README file:

[image: Custom theme flutter app]
Does anyone know what the recommended way is of creating custom layouts like this one? Do I restyle the different parts of the Material Theme?

Answer (score 1):

Some widgets are customized Material Design, often you would create your own if you are looking for custom style.

In the screenshot seems like they are using the material `PageView`, `BottomNavigationBar` but have created a custom slider, switch ext.

It really depends have custom you want your app, Material Design gives you flexibility but it has its limits.

Comment: Okay, thanks! So they changed properties on the BottomNavigationBar like border radius?

Do you have any good guides on creating your own custom widgets?